# How to bind a sortable list to vuejs?

Tags: data-binding, vue.js

I am trying to bind a sortable list in Vue.js, but the underlying data list is not updated:

```js
Vue.component('lessons', {
  template: "#lessons-template",

  data: function() {
    return {
      list: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange: function(evt) {
      console.log(this.list); // allways ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
    }
  },

  ready: function(value) {
    Sortable.create(this.$els.sortable, {
      draggable: 'li',
      onSort: this.onChange
    });
  }
});

new Vue({ el: 'body'});
```

```css
ul { list-style: none;}
ul li { padding: 10px; display: block; background: #EFEFEF; margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>

  <div>
    <lessons></lessons>
  </div>

  <template id="lessons-template">

    <ul v-el:sortable>
      <li v-for="item in list">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    
    <pre>{{ list | json }}</pre>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go:

Vue.js:

```
Vue.component('lessons', {
  template: "#lessons-template",

  data: function() {
    return {
      list: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange: function(evt) {
      console.log(this.list); // allways ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
    }
  },

  ready: function(value) {
    var self = this;
    Sortable.create(this.$els.sortable, {
      draggable: 'li',
      onSort: this.onChange,
      onEnd: function (evt) {
        self.list.splice(evt.oldIndex,1);
        self.list.splice(evt.newIndex,0,evt.item.id);       
    },
    });
  }
});

new Vue({ el: 'body'});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <lessons></lessons>
</div>

<template id="lessons-template">
   <ul v-el:sortable>
     <li v-for="item in list" id="{{item}}">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Working Vue.js Sortable jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/vhsd3wwu/

Comment: I have a problem where it behaves like it isn't bound when I am dragging it and is only bound after I release/place the item. This is an issue for me because I am making AJAX calls in the background and when I get an update Vue inserts a new element so then I have duplicates

Comment: @ErikBerkun-Drevnig You must be doing something wrong with your ajax calls, or most likely, where or where you are running them. Basically, you would run your ajax call on update, otherwise nothing has changed, and there is no need for any calls. This should be pretty straight forward. If you create a fiddle replicating your scenario, I can probably identify the issue for you.

Comment: I was doing it that way so that I could get updates if the list was changed by a different client. Is that not the right way of doing it?

Comment: Your fiddle does not work (Window 10, latest Chrome)

Comment: @Sebi2020 Looks like the url for the sortable library is no longer available.